# Magento 2. What is the purpose of the catalog_eav_attribute table?

Tags: magento2, database

What is the purpose of the `catalog_eav_attribute` table?

Is it in any way related to categories and category attributes? If so, how?

Comment: Basics of EAV Model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: @AndréFerraz thank you. Apples and Oranges though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`catalog_eav_attribute` is an extension of the `eav_attribute` table.
The `eav_attribute` table contains only the general data for all the attributes of all the EAV entities (category, product, customer, customer address, anything custom).
But each EAV entity requires different data for their attributes.
Example "Used in layered navigation". This has no value for the customer attributes but it does for products.
The values in `catalog_eav_attribute` table apply to products and categories attributes only.
Each line in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table has a corresponding line in the `eav_attribute` table. The link is made based on the `attribute_id` field.
Each attribute's properties are determined by the fields in the `eav_attribute` table plus the fields in `catalog_eav_attribute`.

In the same way, there is a table called `customer_eav_attribute` that serves the same purpose for the customer and customer address attributes.

Comment: very clear as always!

Answer (score 0):

`catalog_eav_attribute` is the table where the attribute id will be saved if you create any custom eav attribute using the \Magento\Catalog\Model**::Enity. Something like this code:-

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'yourattr',
            [
                'type'                    => 'varchar',
                'backend'                 => '',
                'frontend'                => '',
                'label'                   => 'yourattr',
                'input'                   => '',
                'class'                   => '',
                'source'                  => '',
                'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible'                 => false,
                'required'                => false,
                'user_defined'            => false,
                'is_system'               => true,
                'default'                 => '',
                'searchable'              => false,
                'filterable'              => false,
                'comparable'              => false,
                'visible_on_front'        => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique'                  => false,
                'apply_to'                => '',
            ]
        );
```

The value of this is actually saved in `eav_attribute` table

I am not sure if they are related directly to categories because categories are different entity type you can check in `eav_entity_type` table

But if you will further check in the `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Setup\CategorySetup.php` file, you will find that `CATEGORY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` constant is related to additional table `catalog_eav_attribute`

Refer to this attribute code `default_sort_by` in the eav_attribute table, so this will be formed if you use the setup code something like this:-

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'yourattrforcategory',
```

Answer (score 0):

> How it works…

Installing a **product attribute** is done in the data install or upgrade scripts. In that script,
we use the **categorySetup** class to add the attributes. In this class, the **addAttribute()**
method is available for adding attributes.

The **addAttribute()** method will create an **EAV attribute** that will be stored in the table
**eav_attribute**. Every **EAV attribute** is from a specific entity type. That’s the reason why
we have retrieved the entity type with the method `$categorySetup>getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);`.

For a product, some information of the attribute (such as the visible_on_front,
used_in_product_listing, and more) is stored in a separate table. This table is the
**catalog_eav_attribute** table where all the extended information of the catalog attributes
is saved. With the **attribute_id** parameter, every row is related to an EAV attribute from
the table **eav_attribute**.